# $(3^n -1)/2 \% c$ where $c$ is a multiple of $2$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Range of $n\le 10^{18},c\le 10^9$

We cannot calculate directly as the numerator is large. I know modulo inverse concept but this can only be applied when denomenator and mod are coprime

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: Does a % b mean remainder when a divided by b?

Comment: yes a%b gives remainder. eg: 5%3=2

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg First off, it's MathJax, not LaTeX. Second, it could be a good idea, since this user is new, to [point them to some resource](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of expecting them to search for it themselves.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a := (3^n -1)/2$. Write $a = qc + r$ where $0 \leq r < c$, so that $r$ is the solution you are looking for. Then we have $2a = q(2c) + 2r$ with $0 \leq 2r < 2c$, so that $2r$ is the solution to
$$3^n -1 \mod{2c}.$$

Solve this equation, divide the solution by two and you are done.